# get omdb api top 100 movies?

Tags: javascript, json, api

need help with omdb api, any way to get 100 top movies from base via omdb api?
I was try to use `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' '&page=1&apikey=??????`, but server answer: 'too many values', maybe anywone can help me to make right callback for this. I'll be very thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, there is no option in Omdb to show top 100 results. But you can  get 100 movies for any search keyword. I found a simple solution by looping through the fetch() and using page parameter. If you execute movie_list() you can get 100 response in an array, and yes you can write the code better, for your use but logic is same.

```
var movie_poster = [];
        function search(variable_from_html_search, i){
        var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=2e1e970c&s=*'+variable_from_html_search+'*&page='+i;
        fetch(url).then(function(resp){
            return resp.json()
        })
        .then(function(data){
            var num = data.Search.length; //to get the length of response, sometimes its less than 10
            for(var j=0; j < num; j++){         
            movie_poster.push(data.Search[j]);
            }
            return movie_poster;    
        });
        return movie_poster;
    };

//loop through search.
    function movie_list(variable_from_html_search){
        var variable_from_html_search = document.getElementById("search").value;

        for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
            movie_poster = search(variable_from_html_search,i);
        }
 //movie_poster now has top 100 list and you can use it anywhere, remember to use JSON.stringify()
```